# Why would Neville be a candidate as the child of the first prophecy?

Tags: harry-potter, prophecy

Sybill Trelawney's prophecy said that the child to face Voldemort would be

> "*born as the seventh month dies.*"

Neville was born on July 30th, Harry on 31st. So isn't the 31st really the last day of the month, **the day the month dies?**

**Since Harry fits the prophecy better (e.g. he was born on the last day of the month), why would Neville even be considered as the child of the prophecy?**

Comment: Also largely a dupe of [Did Lord Voldemort know of Neville's status as a “possible other Prophecy boy”?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/21610/did-lord-voldemort-know-of-nevilles-status-as-a-possible-other-prophecy-boy?s=2|1.0309)

Comment: Related, not dupe; [Would Neville Longbottom Have Survived If Voldemort Had Marked Neville For Death Rather Than Harry?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/7477/would-neville-longbottom-have-survived-if-voldemort-had-marked-neville-for-death)

Comment: Short answer: "as the seventh month dies" means "towards the end of July", not "at the very end of July".

Comment: I feel this is a different question. The linked one is asking why no one else was eligible for the prophesy. This one is asking why Neville was eligible.

Comment: @RogueJedi - er, because he fits the criteria?

Comment: @Richard OP is questioning whether he actually does fit the criteria. "Neville was born on July 30th, Harry on 31st. So isn't 31st really the last day of the month, the day the month dies? Why would Neville even be considered as the child of the prophecy is Harry fits better?" I think it's a valid point.

Comment: @Moogle: I agree with rand al'thor's take - it means "towards the end of July", as in the last few days of July.  Prophecies aren't bus schedules, and are always a bit vague about time and place and person.

Comment: b_jonas' [answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/60662/20774) seems to answer this; *" I always had big plans for Neville. And he really was the boy it could have been. Because, as you know, as I make clear, he was born hours before Harry. He was born on the thirtieth of July. Voldemort singled him out as the other possibility.*" - JKR

Comment: @JohnBode I also agree with that answer. But I still don't think this should be closed as a duplicate, as it's not the same question. I think it should be reopened, and rand al'thor's comment with Richards' quote would be a valid answer.